# Invalid NewPortMappingIndex Using Mono.nat

Tags: vb.net, mono, upnp

I'm trying to open ports, using UPNP to do this I'm using mono.nat

This is my code, its simple and should work, but it throws "Error 402: Invalid NewPortMappingIndex" on the for each. Various other functions of "device" work like GetExternalIP.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler NatUtility.DeviceFound, AddressOf DeviceFound
    NatUtility.StartDiscovery()
End Sub

Private Sub DeviceFound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Mono.Nat.DeviceEventArgs)
    Debug.WriteLine("Found")
    Dim device As INatDevice = e.Device
    Debug.WriteLine(device.GetHashCode)
    For i = 0 To device.GetAllMappings.Length - 1
        Dim _PortMap As Mono.Nat.Mapping = device.GetAllMappings(i)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(_PortMap.Description & " | " & _PortMap.PrivatePort & " | " & _PortMap.Protocol & " | " & _PortMap.PublicPort)
    Next

End Sub
```

I've also tried turning my firewall off and any other thing that could be interfering. I also know for a fact that my router is UPNP enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to loop once too many times:

For i = 0 To device.GetAllMappings.Length

Comment: Oh oops, I did have a - 1 on that but took it off for debugging. So thats not the problem. Thanks anyway. I'm going to fix that now so other people don't make the same mistake. Even if I do `Debug.WriteLine(device.GetAllMappings.Length)` I get the same error.

Comment: How is that call supposed to work btw? You seem to use it to get all the mappings (just for the loop counter) and then use the same function with a index argument -- is this some vb.net syntax I don't understand? I would have assumed that GetAllMappings() returns an array of mappings that you could use...  or if you did want to get a single mapping at a time, you'd use GetSpecificMapping(index)...

Comment: GetAllMappings returns an array, hence why I get the length of it for the loop. It could simple be a `For each _PortMap

Comment: Accidently hit enter above and can't edit it now :( GetAllMappings returns an array, hence why I get the length of it for the loop. It could simple be a `For each _PortMap As Mono.Nat.Mapping in device.GetAllMappings` I just have it like this for testing. GetSpecificMapping takes a port argument, not an index. Also I just realised I get a bunch of other errors: http://i.imgur.com/VNrZDfs.jpg Maybe the mono.nat I'm using is broken?